# Javascript error when trying to set a variable with PUG variable that doesn't exists

Tags: javascript, pug

I have the same form for adding and editing an item.

I have passeed a variable from PUG to JAVASCRIPT like this.

```js
script.
  var loadedItem = !{JSON.stringify(loadedItem)};
```

Later i act upon it

```js
 if (loadedItem) {
   $('select.algs').val(loadedItem.algs).trigger('change');
   $('select.ings').val(loadedItem.ings).trigger('change');
   $('select.spicy').val(loadedItem.spicy).trigger('change');
   $('select.veg').val(loadedItem.veg).trigger('change');
   $('select.cats').val(loadedItem.parent_id).trigger('change');
 }
```

As expected when editing everything works fine.
When routing for a new record (not sending and id to load item),
i get a syntax error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'`

The javascript looks like `var loadedItem=;` which is bad.
Why is this happening? Tnx in advance.

This situation doesn't even let me handle it (can't use `if` because it just does syntax error for `if ()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) here to check for a value otherwise output null (or an empty object or some other object from memory):

```
script.
  var loadedItem = !{ loadedItem ? JSON.stringify(loadedItem) : "null" };
```

Comment: you're great Thank you. i didn't realize it's javascript (`JSON.stringify()`) before it's PUG way of interpolating.